# title в зависимости от сессии и страницы через ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Сессии и текущий язык (локализация) реализованы на клиенте при помощи store.js

После подгрузки всех компонентов мне нужно сменить значение `<title>` на значение из `json`

Сейчас я сделал так:

Сначала проверяется текущая локализация в сессии, потом идет подгрузка языковых констант нужного языка через  `ajax`, потом на все элементы `span` с классом lang ставятся их значения в зависимости от значения атрибута `data-l-id`, потом добавляются нужные скрипты компонентов с нужной локализацией.

А как быть с названием страницы, которое указывается в `<title>`? Ведь приложение одностраничное, но страниц много и локализаций 4.

Comment: Я может быть ошибаюсь, но разве нельзя простым `$("title").html(valueFromJson);` ? Ведь title такой же элемент html как и все остальное. Просто при загрузке страницы у тебя уже есть нужная локаль, и по данной локали ты грузишь дату на наужном языке. И после прогрузки ты можешь ее прицепить куда угодно.

Comment: @alexoander, я тоже так думал, но почему-то не меняется((

Comment: Покажи код, где ты обрабатываешь полученный json из ajax и как ты его пытаешься прицепить к title